# Date Calculation as HH.Mi format in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, plsql

I am migrating a query from Oracle to sql server.That query contains some date calculations.It calculates total work hour  in hour:mi format.Could you help me to convert it because Datediff doesnt contain HH:Mi format and i am new at sql server so i dont know how to work that query in Mssql.Except for Mod,All of functions in the following query,i created in mssql.

```
SELECT dbo.TRIM(dbo.TO_CHAR(dbo.TRUNC(MOD((dbo.TO_DATE (MAX (END_HOUR),'HH24.MI') -
  dbo.TO_DATE (MIN (START_HOUR),'HH24.MI'))* 24,24)),'00'))  + ':'   
+ dbo.TRIM(dbo.TO_CHAR(dbo.TRUNC(MOD((dbo.TO_DATE(MAX(END_HOUR),'HH24.MI') - 
dbo.TO_DATE(MIN (START_HOUR),'HH24.MI'))* 24* 60,60)),'00')) TOTAL_TIME   FROM MY_TABLE 
 WHERE ID_PERSON in(  307,294,291,290,292,293)   AND DS_DATE BETWEEN 
 dbo.TO_DATE ('01.03.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy') AND dbo.TO_DATE('03.05.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a triviel statement to port. So if i had to do it, i vould start by taking the statement apart in its components:

`dbo.TRIM(dbo.TO_CHAR(dbo.TRUNC(MOD((dbo.TO_DATE (MAX (END_HOUR),'HH24.MI') - dbo.TO_DATE (MIN (START_HOUR),'HH24.MI'))* 24,24)),'00'))`

and

`dbo.TRIM(dbo.TO_CHAR(dbo.TRUNC(MOD((dbo.TO_DATE(MAX(END_HOUR),'HH24.MI') - dbo.TO_DATE(MIN (START_HOUR),'HH24.MI'))* 24* 60,60)),'00'))`

and then trying to break down each of those into smaller parts.

The `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` can be done by using the TSql `convert(### as datetime)` and `cast(### as varchar)`

The `TRIM`, `TRUNC`, `MOD`, `MIN` and `MAX` you should be able to find equivalents for in TSql.

The Transact-SQL reference is found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `HH:MI` format when I tried to migrate Oracle queries to sql. I found the following workaround:

```
CAST(CAST(getdate() as time(0)) as varchar(5)) "Time inn HHMI format"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to get the total time an employee worked in the period.
If you have the records with starting datetime and ending datetime you just could use math on the datetime-datatype.

If you would like to get the working time of one day, just do something like:

```
select time1, time2, convert (varchar(8),time2-time1,108) from timecalc
```

The datetime datatype is a number, staring at 1.1.1900. So if the datetime-values differ by 6 hours you get 1900-01-01 06:00:00.000 as a result.

You could convert that to varchar to work with that and to get hours and minutes, like in the example i posted 06:00:00.

To work with minutes and seconds, you use:

```
dateadd()


Convert(type, value, format)
```

type:

```
Convert(Varchar(8),date, 108)
```

For detailed information about the formats:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx